# Forecast multiple columns with for-loop

Tags: r, smoothing, forecasting

I'm new with R (and programming), and I have to make as simple exponential smoothing forecast for 216 different products.

example:

```
items <- dataset 

Date     A      B      C  
01-10    3      1      7 
02-10    4      2      0  
03-10    9      2      1 
04-10    8      1      3
```

I got:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(items)) { 
  col <- ts(items[,i]) 
  fcast <- ses(col, h=12) 
  write.table(fcast, file ="test.csv",sep=";", dec=",") 
} 

Error: not compatible with REALSXP
```

Am I doing everything wrong, or am I on the right track?... please help me

Comment: Your example does not seem to produce the error you mention. It would be useful if you provide the output of `traceback()`; this helps locating the actual problem.  BTW, you are also forecasting the first column (Date) -- does this make sense? Also the error msg suggests that you are trying to use a data that is not a number where a number is expected. Maybe you apply ses() or ts() to a character column?

Comment: > traceback()
6: stop(list(message = "not compatible with REALSXP", call = NULL, 
       cppstack = NULL))
5: etsTargetFunctionInit(par = par, y = y, nstate = nstate, errortype = errortype, 
       trendtype = trendtype, seasontype = seasontype, damped = damped, 
       par.noopt = par.noopt, lowerb = lower, upperb = upper, opt.crit = opt.crit, 
       nmse = nmse, bounds = bounds, m = m, pnames = names(par), 
       pnames2 = names(par.noopt))
4: etsmodel(y, errortype[i], trendtype[j], seasontype[k], damped[l], 
       alpha, beta, gamma, phi, lower = lower, upper = upper,

Comment: opt.crit = opt.crit, 
       nmse = nmse, bounds = bounds, ...)
3: ets(x, "ANN", alpha = alpha, opt.crit = "mse")
2: forecast(ets(x, "ANN", alpha = alpha, opt.crit = "mse"), h, level = level, 
       fan = fan, ...)
1: ses(col, h = 12) at #3

Comment: sounds most likely, but how do I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
# library("forecast")
for(i in 1:ncol(items)) { 
  col <- ts(items[,i]) 
  fcast <- ses(col, h=12) 
  write.table(fcast, file =paste("test", i, ".csv", sep="") ,sep=";", dec=",") 
}
```

Althogh I didnt get any error with your code.

For my example `item` is a `data.frame` look at `dput` output:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(1:4, .Label = c("01-10", "02-10", 
"03-10", "04-10"), class = "factor"), A = c(3L, 4L, 9L, 8L), 
    B = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), C = c(7L, 0L, 1L, 3L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

where the first column is `factor` and the others are `integer`

Comment: could it be that, the data is read as a 45x216 character matrix??

Comment: okay I think I see what your doing, but I have 216 rows. so how do i make first row factor, and the rest of the rows integer? or do I have to manually refer to all of them?

Comment: Just needed to type 'items=as.data.frame(items)'... thanks alot fellows, you are amazing!